# What's wrong with this mysql create trigger statement

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TRIGGER google_inventory BEFORE UPDATE ON `cataloginventory_stock_item`
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
   update `catalog_product_entity_int` 
   set value=20 
   where attribute_id=552 
          and entity_id=NEW.product_id 
          and NEW.is_in_stock=0;
   update `catalog_product_entity_int` 
   set value=21 
   where attribute_id=552 
          and entity_id=NEW.product_id 
          and NEW.is_in_stock=1;
  END;
```

It gives me the following error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '' at line 4

I'm a SQL Server guy by trade and can't put my finger on what the issue is.

Comment: what is NEW.product_id and NEW.is_in_stock?  is it from another table, if so then you need to join on it

Comment: New is the trigger syntax that refers to the changes that are being made in the table as per this doc http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to change the delimiter. Without it, semicolon is ending CREATE TRIGGER statement.

```
delimiter |

CREATE TRIGGER google_inventory BEFORE UPDATE ON `cataloginventory_stock_item`
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
   update `catalog_product_entity_int` 
   set value=20 
   where attribute_id=552 
          and entity_id=NEW.product_id and NEW.is_in_stock=0;
   update `catalog_product_entity_int` 
   set value=21 
   where attribute_id=552 
          and entity_id=NEW.product_id and NEW.is_in_stock=1;
  END;
|

delimiter ;
```

Comment: glad I asked... I never would have come up with that on my own limited mysql experience.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The semicolons in your trigger are screwing it up.  You have to use the `DELIMITER` keyword to change the delimiter that MySQL is using.

From http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html:

```
mysql> delimiter //

mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE simpleproc (OUT param1 INT)
    -> BEGIN
    ->   SELECT COUNT(*) INTO param1 FROM t;
    -> END//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> delimiter ;
```